# Polymer with highmaps:cannot read property mapChart of undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts, polymer, highmaps

I am trying to provide a wrapper of polymer on highmap using the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon/
but it is throwing an error can not read property mapChart of undefined, can someone please provide a working jsfiddle of highmap using polymer?

```
  <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 <script 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>

  <script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js">
 </script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js">
</script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/gb/gb-all.js">
  </script>


 <dom-module id="high-map">
<template>
  <div id="container"></div>
<style>
#container {
    height: 100x;
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
</style>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
    is: "high-map",
    attached: function () {


        $(this.$.container).Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic lat/lon demo'
},

mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true
},

tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>Lat: {point.lat}, Lon: {point.lon}'
},

series: [{
    // Use the gb-all map with no data as a basemap
    mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/gb/gb-all'],
    name: 'Basemap',
    borderColor: '#A0A0A0',
    nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3)',
    showInLegend: false
}, {
    name: 'Separators',
    type: 'mapline',
    data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/gb/gb-all'], 'mapline'),
    color: '#707070',
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false
}, {
    // Specify points using lat/lon
    type: 'mappoint',
    name: 'Cities',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
    data: [{
        name: 'London',
        lat: 51.507222,
        lon: -0.1275
    }, {
        name: 'Birmingham',
        lat: 52.483056,
        lon: -1.893611
    }, {
        name: 'Leeds',
        lat: 53.799722,
        lon: -1.549167
    }, {
        name: 'Glasgow',
        lat: 55.858,
        lon: -4.259
    }, {
        name: 'Sheffield',
        lat: 53.383611,
        lon: -1.466944
    }, {
        name: 'Liverpool',
        lat: 53.4,
        lon: -3
    }, {
        name: 'Bristol',
        lat: 51.45,
        lon: -2.583333
    }, {
        name: 'Belfast',
        lat: 54.597,
        lon: -5.93
    }, {
        name: 'Lerwick',
        lat: 60.155,
        lon: -1.145,
        dataLabels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 5,
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        }
         }]
        }]
     });

     }
    });
   </script>
 </dom-module>
```

Comment: The link you provided is working fine.

Comment: @Ofisora yes but the wrapper of polymer on highchart is not working, i have posted the code which is not working the jsfiddle code was for reference

Comment: I thought the jsfiddle was your polymer code. Anyway, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for initializing the chart is wrong. Read the documentation [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started).

Change your code

`$(this.$.container).Highcharts.mapChart('container', {`

to

`Highcharts.mapChart(this.$.container, {`

Or,

`$(this.$.container).highcharts('Map', {`

then it will work.

[Working Demo in Polymer](http://plnkr.co/edit/e04DqAD0MuLtnOlGP3dS?p=preview)

Comment: i should have gone through the documentation first i copied the fiddle , thanks its working